# Why does my refractive object render with an offset?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image: LookDev Mode in Viewport]

[image: Render output]

I followed a tutorial on youtube to make a black hole, this was my fourth or fifth as the otherones would create a result of the black hole reflecting/refracting itself. In the viewport it looks bery seamless but in the render it 'cuts off' or 'jumps' in the accretion disk.

EDIT: Something I forgot to mention is that I'm using two different objects for the accretion disk, one for the emissive dust and one for the non-emissive dust. Also I was encountering errors when trying to upload to blend-exchange.com so that's why I haven't attached a .blend

Comment: You might wanna share your file on blender-exchange.com so people can take a look. Edit your answer and paste the code given by the site into it.

Comment: While it's uploading I'm realizing it might be something to do with the denoising as it looks fine before denoising

Comment: Sounds plausible. If that's the case, you can write that as an answer to your own question, and mark it as accepted, so other people in the future might benefit. Thanks!

Comment: I've narrowed the problem down to the SuperImageDenoiser addon, I'm going to try updating it to see if that fixes it because I haven't since Blender 3.1 or 3.2 (I'm currently on Blender 3.4.1 by the way)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to not use SuperImageDenoiser, as for some reason if using two objects for the accretion disk, the addon only passes one through the refractive material, in this case the emissive disk. The non-emissive disk works fine in every part of the render except the refraction around the 'hole', and the only fix I've found so far was to use the regular denoise node as opposed to the SID.

Comment: I've further narrowed the issue down to the difference between the Transmisison Indirect and the Transmission Direct passes, for some reason the TransDir pass contains the refraction of the black hole in addition to a colored emissive portion of the accretion disk while the indirect only contains a colorless non-emissive portion of the accretion disk, an so the SID adds the grey portion onto an already brightly colored colored/emissive portion and that pass is lost. I'm going to try to use the experiment with the volumetric passes to find a work around that retains all of the accretion disk.